# How to let only authorized user access to some files?

Tags: php, security, apache

Here is the situation:
I have an Apache server , which hosting a php program, the program allow user to login and the user can upload files, and share their upload files to others, so, I have a folder called "attachment" in the htdoc folders, which is store the user's attachement.  But I don't want people get access to this folder directly, I only let some users(base on their user right), to get the file they want, others, can get access to that file...

For example, A upload file_a, and share with B, C. User B, C can dl the link via a link, but User D even he/she got the link, but he/she still can't download, even he/she is logging or not. How can I do this checking? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to make the folder private (i.e.: move it out of `htdocs`) and use a gateway script. Something like this:

```
$fullpath = '/path/to/your/files/'.basename($_GET['filename']));

// verify that the user is valid here
// verify that file exists here

// get the mime type
$finfo = finfo_open();
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $fullpath, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

// send it to the client
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fullpath));
header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
readfile($fullpath);
```

So, you'd link to it like:

http://yourdomain.com/files.php?filename=foobar.zip

Comment: You can append more GET params, like some encrypted data generated by actual time and UserID to be sure that certain user has permission for downloading some file(s).

example:
`http://yourdomain.com/files.php?filename=foobar.zip&id=d90abc8374&checkstate=ff94ad0e5700`

Answer (score 2):

Don't keep a file as a blob in your db... instead, keep the file outside of your web directory, then have a php file that checks access, and serves the file to people if they have correct access.

```
        $file = 'file_path';
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"filename.jpg\"");
        header('Cache-Control: private');
        header('Pragma: private');
        $fp = fopen($file,"rb");
        fpassthru($fp);
        fclose($fp);
        exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

1. Put the file in a blob, and track the permissions in the application.
2. Slightly less secure, but easier to implement:  give no one access to the actual files, then generate a symbolic link using a uuid, but only allow it to persist for the duration of the download.
3. Give each user their own directory that only they have access to (htaccess) and create symbolic links to each of the files they should have access to in that directory.

Number 1 is the cleanest, but the other two are workable solutions.